# Can't compile Rust

Tags: llvm, rust

I'm on Debian and following the compile instructions from the Rust wiki: https://github.com/mozilla/rust/wiki/Doc-getting-started

I tried a couple of times but it always ends up with the following error:

```
llvm[3]: Compiling opt.cpp for Release+Asserts build
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `/home/user/rust/llvm/x86_64-unknown-linux-
gnu/tools/lib/libLLVMipo.a', needed by `/home/user/rust/llvm/x86_64-unknown-
linux-gnu/Release+Asserts/bin/opt'.  Stop.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/rust/llvm/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/
tools/opt'
make[2]: *** [opt/.makeall] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/rust/llvm/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/tools'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/rust/llvm/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
make: *** [/home/user/rust/llvm/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/Release+Asserts/
bin/llvm-config]  Error 2
```

**Edit:**

The problem only occurs whithin a debootstrap/chroot environment, not within a full Debian Installation.

Comment: I may have had a similar problem, I think I fixed it by changing my default python (find yours by `which python`) to python2 instead of python3 (llvm uses python2 to build)

Comment: Does this still happen? I tried in a chroot (using `systemd-nspawn`), and could not reproduce.

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to these instructions:

```
git clone git://github.com/mozilla/rust.git
cd rust
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make check
```

...I can see at least one thing wrong with them. Try this instead:

```
git clone git://github.com/mozilla/rust.git
cd rust
git submodule update --init
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The `git submodule update --init` is necessary to initialize Rust's submodules, which include LLVM and libuv.

Answer (score 1):

`git submodule update` shouldn't be needed, as Rust's configure script tries to handle that itself, but if you run `git submodule status` and see lines about changes to `src/libuv` or `src/llvm` then it could be a problem.

I haven't seen that error before and can't tell what's wrong from that snippet. Possibly run `make clean-all` then gist the full output of `./configure && make`, as well as the contents of config.mk. Also, you will probably get more attention with this question on the rust bug tracker: http://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues